# Spring data elasticsearch-from/size

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

how to set **from/size** of search result executed using  spring `Elasticsearchtemplate`.

- while same functionality can be performed using out of the box `elasticsearch API`

  NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().node().client().prepareSearch("wsearchobject")
                  .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                   .setFrom(10)
                  .setSize(20)
                  .execute().actionGet();

how to set from and size parameters using `elasticsearchtemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `PageRequest` .
Details can be found at [Spring Data Elasticsearch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)

you can refer Example 2. PagingAndSortingRepository from doc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not available in spring data framework yet.

Link:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-187&usg=ALkJrhhjX4MjwaEWTnG5v-qucDQBlqVWXg